# Two Minimalistic Ways to place and display a single-graphic svg in HTML

Tags: php, html, caching, svg, inline

`// Updated question, skip the comments section, since all hints are implemented here //`

Given a simple svg file `logo.svg` containing ***only 1 graphic(!)*** and an html page where we want to place the graphic into, ***with as little code as is barely possible*** in the most minimalistic way...

---

Method 1: works perfectly! but no caching as the whole svg becomes inline in the html source:

```
<? include("logo.svg")?>
```

---

Method 2: Broken! Greyed "image missing icon" while the file exists and shows as xml file like [here](https://davidwalsh.name/serve-svg-image)

```
<img src="logo.svg" />
```

[image]

---

Add to .htaccess but still the exact same problem! (images below)

```
# interpret svg files as image instead of xml
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

Final step: **how to have external files with svg contents display as graphics, instead of xml?**

---

logo.svg

```
<svg  viewBox="0 0 200 200"  id="svglogo">
<path d="m151.4 63.7c0.2 0 23.5 2 37.7-10.9 6.6-6 10.3-14.3
         11-24.7v-28.1h-200.1v31.9c0.7 10.4 4.4 18.7 11 247" />
</svg>
```

---

[image]

Comment: Code `<img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/DroidSans-Bold.svg">` works for me when I try it. No idea why the same syntax doesn't work for you. Is the file accessible by the webserver?

Comment: `<img src="logo.svg" alt="logo"></img>` - possibly doesn't work as that's not technically valid HTML, `<img .. />` doesn't have a closing tag, it should just be `<img src="logo.svg" alt="logo" />` (if you're XML formatting it)

Comment: @apokryfos, the file loads and displays perfectly using method 1, as stated in the question. So I dont think its a wevserver problem...

Comment: But using method one you read the file in the backend. WIth methods 2 and 3 the browser is instructed to download the file when the page is loaded so the webserver needs to serve it.

Comment: @apokryfos Aaaah I see what you mean! so to answer your question i must be able to load/read the file www.domain.com/logo.svg and see if its a readable file yes?

Comment: Yes. That's what I was asking (It never occurred to me that the HTML formatting was that strict)

Comment: @apokryfos +1 and (unfortunately) the file shows up as readable svg xml code in the browser so there must the something else missing in the html code for getting Method 2 working... If you try `<svg>` and a path to the separate svg file, does that work for you?

Comment: The 2nd way doesn't work for me, however https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use does note it as deprecated

Comment: @apokryfos @CD001  Oops my mistake! The `<img src="logo.svg" />` still doesnt work! What showed up was the php include method! With the <img method I get a small square grayed missing image icon showing. When i select the "show image" then the svg file shows as a redable xml data. So the `<img>` method is still broken... any ideas what I can try now?

Comment: No idea. Check https://jsfiddle.net/bh1p07je/ it works for me. If it doesn't work for you then your browser may be acting oddly. If it does work then that kind of reinforces the notion of there's something odd with accessing the file. Check the browser network console as well to see if there are errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146554/discussion-between-sam-and-apokryfos).

Comment: Aaah thanks Now I see Interestingly enoug... the link in your first post (way first) has no closing tag `>` and that dit NOT work in my FireFox 50, however, cloding the tag `/>` makes al characters appear I guess that is the "graphic" which I am supposed to see? !@^#&*)$ ABCD etc. So thats a start...

Comment: I think it has to do with my apache server .htaccess something with AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz not being compatible since it sees the file as an xml while it should make it an image I think  https://davidwalsh.name/serve-svg-image

Comment: Strange thing is that even after adding `AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz` to .htaccess, it still shows broken image and reads svg as an xml file!! I will rewrite the question! Thanks sofar for all hints! Greatly appreciated and very helpfull sofar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of tryouts and comparison with why other svgs worked and my clean svg didnt, it appears all was set correctly (even .htaccess file) except:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" id="svglogo">  // svg shows as numeric xml
```

had to be:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" id="svglogo"
     version="1.1"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
```

And after setting these three extra parameters the svg is shown as a graphic.
Actually the fourth and last line is the essential part. Without this line all is read as in the original question: boring xml data sheet. With it it becomes a graphic! The other two lines (second and third) could be removed and the graphic will show, as long as the last line is in place.